# Using Statesman with Racsack to return particular states from dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

How do I use Ransack (with a dropdown menu of the states from Statesman) to return a subset of data from my collection?

Example;

Here is my dropdown;

```
<select class="select" name="q[state_machine_current_state_eq]" id="q_state_machine_current_state_eq">
    <option selected="selected" value="pending">pending</option>
    <option value="active">active</option>
</select>
```

A record can either be "pending" or "active".

Here is my controller index method;

```
def index
  @filter = current_sponsor
    .card_holders
    .ransack(params[:q])
  @sponsor_card_holders = @filter
    .result
    .page(params[:page])
    .per(3)
    .decorate
end
```

If I do a `binding.pry` now I can get this for `@filter`;

```
Ransack::Search<class: User::CardHolder, base: Grouping <combinator: and>>
```

For `@sponsor_card_holders.first.current_state`

```
"active"
```

For `params[:q]`

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"state_machine_current_state_eq"=>"active"} permitted: false>
```

I think my issue is almost certainly the `state_machine_current_state_eq` part in my dropdown html. I've basically made an educated guess. I also tried `current_state_eq`.

I am expecting it to return something like;

```
Ransack::Search<class: User::CaseWorker, base: Grouping <conditions: [Condition <attributes: ["card_holder_state_machine"], predicate: eq, values: ["active"]>]>
```

But it's ignoring the dropdown. What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, this was a bit more complex than I was anticipating. I was hoping that I just had to change `state_machine_current_state_eq` active to something else and it would all work.

Actually though, you have to create a custom Ransackable Scope;

**app/models/user/card_holder.rb**

```
scope :current_state, -> (state) do 
  # because "pending" won't exist in the database as it's the default state
  if state == 'pending'
    left_outer_joins(:transitions).where(card_holder_transitions: {to_state: nil})
  # else return all the requested "states" (but only the most recent)
  # most_recent: true is very important here for obvious reasons
  else
    joins(:transitions).where(card_holder_transitions: {most_recent: true}).where(card_holder_transitions: {to_state: state})
  end
end

def self.ransackable_scopes(auth_object = nil)
  %i(
    current_state
  )
end
```

Then you can just call `:current_state` in your Ransack dropdown.

I hope this helps someone some day!

Comment: You just saved my day! Though the only change I had to do was rename `transitions` to `card_holder_transitions` on the joins. Nice tip about the default state as well.